# Clearing a dropdown menu in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two drop down boxes in my program. When you select an item from the first drop down, it populates select-able items in the second. When I select something in the second and then change the selection in the first one, the values remain in the second. How do I "reset" the second drop down when the first is changed?

Any help would be awesome!

The drop down is in a windows form.

Comment: Combobox (ASP.Net) or DropDownList (Windows Forms)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to reset the comboxBox items collection before adding the new items :

```
comboBox.Items.Clear()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with very old VB.NET legacy code in an ASP.NET project, so I'm not sure if this answer will help anyone or not.  Here is what I did to clear our dropdown list:

```
ddlCategory.ClearSelection()
```

The code in the .aspx file looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" Style="width:250px">
```

ClearSelection() did exactly what I needed it to do.  It cleared the dropdownlist selection so that nothing was selected.  The box was blank, but when you dropdown the list, all the options are still available to choose from.